# take too nicely with

Tags: meaning, idioms

> Squidward doesn't take too nicely with SpongeBob until he tells
> Squidward of the millions of tiny TV people watching.

https://blaze-and-the-monster-machines.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:Puppylove1257/The_Great_SpongeBob_Adventure

I don't understand what that mean. It doesn't sound too idiomatic. Should the "with" be there? I would think it should have been "doesn't take SpongeBob too nicely", but I am not sure. Is this an idiom? I couldn't find it in the dictionary.

Comment: The whole text is full of errors (it's a fan page) and I suspect the writer may not be a native English speaker, or may not be a professional writer.

Comment: It’s a mistake. The right phrase is *takes kindly to*. Don’t use fan pages as places to learn English.